A question on an isomorphism between ${\rm PSL}_2(9)$ and $A_6$
I found a nice argument proving that ${\rm PSL}_2(9)\cong A_6$ on page 52 of The finite simple groups by Prof. R.A. Wilson.

Let $f:A_6\to S_{{\rm PL}(9)}$ with $(123)^f= z\mapsto z+1$, $(456)^f= z\mapsto z+i$ and $(14)(23)^f= z\mapsto-\frac{1}{z}$. I have checked that $f$  is well-defined on other elements, which means in addition to our labelings of $(123|456)$ as $\infty$ and $(423|156)$ as $0$, we can label $(134|256)$ as $1$, $(124|356)$ as $2$, $(235|146)$ as $i$, $(135|246)$ as $i+1$, $(125|346)$ as $i+2$, $(236|145)$ as $2i$, $(136|245)$ as $2i+1$, $(126|345)$ as $2i+2$, and I have checked this labeling is consistent with our definition of $f$.
I know that $A_6$ is generated by $(123)$, $(456)$ and $(14)(23)$. And I have also shown that ${\rm PSL}_2(9)$ is generated by $z\mapsto z+1$, $z\mapsto z+i$ and $z\mapsto-\frac{1}{z}$. The only thing that confuses me is how to show that $f$ is a homomorphism. My first thought was that it would suffice to check the multiplication of each pair of generators. But that is clearly not sufficient in general.
Do we need to check all the $A_{360}^2$ multiplications between the pairs of elements? But I don't think that is what the author means.
So my question is: how to show that $f$ is a homomorphism?

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

No, you don't need to check multiplications on all pairs of elements by hand, and you basically never want to do that kind of computation.
To start with, we have a group action of $A_6$ on the partitions, by $$\sigma \cdot (a,b,c\ |\ x,y,z) = \left (\sigma(a),\sigma(b),\sigma(c)\ |\ \sigma(x),\sigma(y),\sigma(z) \right).$$
Whenever you have a group action, you immediately get a homomorphism into the symmetric group, so a homomorphism $f: A_6 \rightarrow S_{10}$ in this case.
Also, from the natural action $\operatorname{PSL}_2(9)$ on $10$ points (projective line), we may consider $\operatorname{PSL}_2(9) < S_{10}$.
The argument described by Wilson then shows that with a suitable labelling of the points, we have $f((123))$ equal to the map $z \mapsto z+1$ in $\operatorname{PSL}_2(9)$, etc., eventually concluding that $f$ is an isomorphism.
